# Confluent kafka create_topics is failing to create kafka topics from pycharm but works fine from python terminal

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pycharm

I am just playing around with confluent kafka python APIs. Here I am running a 3 worker kafka cluster service on local (***localhost:9902,localhost:9903,localhost:9904***) and trying to create a topic via python API of confluent kafka using below function

```
from confluent_kafka import admin
from typing import Union

consumer_config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'
}

# utils function for creating new kafka topics 

def create_new_topics(names: Union[str, list], partitions: int = 1, replication: int = 1):
    if isinstance(names, str):
        names = names.split(',')
    new_topics = [admin.NewTopic(name, partitions, replication) for name in names]
    fs = admin.AdminClient(consumer_config).create_topics(new_topics, validate_only=False)

    for topic, f in fs.items():
        try:
            f.result()  # The result itself is None
            print("Topic {} created".format(topic))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to create topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))
    return admin.AdminClient(consumer_config).list_topics().topics
```

But calling this function from PyCharm resulting in below kafka exception and topics are not getting created. But If I am running it in a python terminal, it works !!

```
#Calling the above utils function for topic creation 

topics=['test1','test2']
create_new_topics(topics)   

#Exception received in Pycharm

Failed to create topic test1: KafkaError{code=_DESTROY,val=-197,str="Handle is terminating: Success"}
Failed to create topic test2: KafkaError{code=_DESTROY,val=-197,str="Handle is terminating: Success"}
```

I am not understanding what's the issue with Pycharm alone! Is there any listener configuration I need to add for pycharm ?

Comment: Can you check from the commandline whether these topics already exists or not ?

Comment: @AmalGJose Nope they are new. Every time I am deleting the /tmp/ directory and so the topics for new tests. And topics are getting created from terminal using same above code while exception is thrown from pycharm execution

Comment: Try this snippet and let me know whether this is working or not. The logic to list the topics is not included. 

https://gist.github.com/amalgjose/bae43867217e880c58c61278293c2fe0

Comment: This is the same solution given by confluent team for similar issue on this thread : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1257 right!! It's not working and it is just putting the same functionality as of mine in  an instance method with some additional debug level . And this debug level will print all logs from broker, admin and protocol . This won't resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, this is the same code. Pasted it to another gist for clarity. Check the code in this thread. Check the last comment.
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1298

Comment: @AmalGJose Yep that helps. So that's a bug. We need to instantiate the client first and use the client object for calling the create_topics or delete_topics methods instead of doing it in the same line.

Comment: Btw, topic metadata is stored in Zookeeper, so clearing /tmp topic data won't truly remove them

Comment: @OneCricketeer : Yep I know .. My Zookeeper directory and kafka log directories are under /tmp/ :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in existing confluent Kafka python API as reported in this link : [github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1298](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1298)

As a work around we can instantiate the client first and then use the client object for accessing create_topics and delete_topics methods

Below code works :

```
from confluent_kafka import admin
from typing import Union

consumer_config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'
}

# Admin client instantiation 
client = admin.AdminClient(consumer_config)

# Function for creating topics
def create_new_topics(names: Union[str, list], partitions: int = 1, replication: int = 1):
    if isinstance(names, str):
        names = names.split(',')
    new_topics = [admin.NewTopic(name, partitions, replication) for name in names]
    
    # Accessing admin create_topics via admin client 
    
    fs = client.create_topics(new_topics, validate_only=False)

    for topic, f in fs.items():
        try:
            f.result()  # The result itself is None
            print("Topic {} created".format(topic))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to create topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))

#Calling the above utils function for topic creation 

topics=['test1','test2']
create_new_topics(topics)
```